# substring or rtrim

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have a field called LastWebpage, in the Field it stores the webpage .asp pagename
I have to write a script where i just need to take the `jl_AssessmentDirect.asp` name instead of `4000_1_jl_AssessmentDirect.asp`. How do i get rid of `4000_1_`. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more examples?  It's not clear from your single example whether that text to be removed is always the same and can be hard-coded, or has a more complex pattern.

Comment: Is `4000_1_` a constant? is the size (7 characters) a constant? Is everything to the right of the second underscore character a constant? What is the pattern?

Comment: Please accept the answer that helps the most if it does what you want (big tick on the left). And/or vote up. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to do this, I assume the data is not always the same, this is just to show you how the functions work

right or replace is my preferred method

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @v = '4000_1_jl_AssessmentDirect.asp'

SELECT REPLACE(@v,'4000_1_','')
```

or

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @v = '4000_1_jl_AssessmentDirect.asp'

DECLARE @r VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @r ='4000_1_'

--if you have spaces RTRIM and LTRIM everything
SELECT RIGHT(@v,LEN(@v) -LEN(@r))
```

If stuff changes, you can dump it in variables

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @v = '4000_1_jl_AssessmentDirect.asp'

DECLARE @r VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @r ='4000_1_'

SELECT REPLACE(@v,@r,'')
```

Ideally you want to update such columns to only have the URL and nothing else

Comment: Sorry i did not see that LastWebPage Column has more Page name start with 4000 0r 1 0r 2. I just need the value to start with jl and i don't want anything in front of it. Can i use Substring function for it

Comment: post DDL and some DML data so that we can write a solution that you can run

Answer (score 1):

"It depends"

- If always "4000_1_", use REPLACE as per SQLMenace's answer.
- If a fixed length of any string, use SUBSTRING. No need to work out LENGTH first

`SUBSTRING(MyValue, 8, 8000)`

- If the right hand side is fixed length and the unwanted part is variable length, use RIGHT
- If both sides are variable, you'll need something like

`SUBSTRING(MyValue, PATINDEX('%[_]1[_]%', MyValue) + 3, 8000)`

Edit:

If you always want "jl"...

```
SUBSTRING(MyValue, PATINDEX('%jl%', MyValue), 8000)
```

Comment: I updated my RIGHT() answer with variables `SELECT RIGHT(@v,LEN(@v) -LEN(@r))`

Comment: +1 for PATINDEX suggestion.  I'd never heard of that keyword before, so +1 just for teaching me something new.

Comment: Sorry guys i used SubString(LastWebpage, PatINDEX('%[_]1[_]%',LastWebpage) +3, 8000), but with the small Page name its cutting the starting name : For example: _LocDirect.asp
I just need to start any page name with jl_pagename

Comment: @Faizan: I've updated my answer since you said "always starts jl"

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the suggestions here already you can use [stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx).

```
declare @s varchar(100)
set @s = '4000_1_jl_AssessmentDirect.asp'

select stuff(@s, 1, 7, '')
```

Remove characters before `jl`

```
declare @s varchar(100)
set @s = '4000_1_jl_AssessmentDirect.asp'

select stuff(@s, 1, charindex('jl', @s)-1, '')
```